# Why do we say "a Bologna" but "in Italia"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Why do I say *io vado **a** Bologna* (city) and *io vado **in** Italia* (country)?

For example, I can’t say *io vado **ad** Italia*.

Why do we always use *in* (not *a*) for countries and *a* (not *in*) for cities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is more a question of usage rather than logic. The following material can help:

**La preposizione IN** esprime il complemento di luogo e quindi risponde alla domanda "dove?" o "verso dove?", in particolare si usa con i verbi di stato o di movimento davanti a:

> - nomi di nazione:
>     Sono in Italia.
>     Vado in Marocco.
> - nomi di grandi isole e regioni:
>     Abito in Sicilia.
>     Lavoro in Normandia.
> - nomi delle vie:
>     Abito in via San Vitale 10.

**La preposizione A** esprime il complemento di luogo, ovvero risponde alla domanda "dove?" o "verso dove?" e si usa con i verbi di stato o di movimento.

> Alcuni esempi:
>
> - a casa, a scuola, a teatro, a pranzo, a cena, a colazione, a letto.
> - Si usa davanti ai nomi di città:
>     Abito a Milano.
>     Studio a Londra.

Source: http://www.zanichellibenvenuti.it/wordpress/?p=385

Comment: To summarise, and somewhat explain, in English: in principle *in* denotes a place somebody or something stays in, while *a* denotes the destination of a movement. But in the current usage the two are often exchanged, and the nature of the place tends to dictate the preposition to be used: whether it is a city, a country, a street..., as in the examples given. So, for instance, you'll use *in* for towns only in rare, formal situations: a bureaucratic-sounding *ditta con sede in Roma*, say.

Comment: Now I'm pretty much confused with these rare cases, but anyway your comment made things more clear.. thanks

Comment: @Hatem  Alimam - my suggestion is to learn them without much thinking about it. Usage will come natural after a while. Same problem with English with the use of to/in/into/...