# Using a or in about a place

Tags: translation, prepositions

I would like someone to explain simply the difference between using 'a' or 'in' when talking about a place. An example of what I mean is a page title 'Walking in Florence'. Should it be

camminare a Firenze

or

camminare in Firenze

I am finding it hard to shake the English language idea that you do something 'inside' a place rather than 'at' a place.

Comment: Please try to have a look at [this](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/usage-of-prepositions-a-and-in-in-statements-about-places-and-directions) and [this](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/why-do-we-say-a-bologna-but-in-italia).

Comment: Also note that in your case it might be "camminare **per** Firenze" rather than "camminare **a** Firenze" (certainly not "camminare **in** Firenze").

Comment: What I actually want to Use as a Subject line is 'Geocaching in Florence', written in Italian, but I didn't think anyone would know what Geocaching is.

Comment: "Geocaching a Firenze" is OK - if you are concerned that the readers might have never heard of "geocaching" add a short detail, for example "Geocaching a Firenze (caccia al tesoro!)".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It is clever and obvious at the same time. I am gratifies that you actually know what I am talking about No I have to write the body of the blog entry VERY VERY SLOWLY :)